# How to make adf.test print more precise p-value in R

Tags: r, precision, suppress-warnings, p-value

I make a simple cointegration function using add.test from tseries packages

```
cointegration <- function(vals)
{
    library(tseries)

    beta <- coef(lm(vals[,2] ~ vals[,1] + 0, data = vals))[1]
    names(beta) <- NULL
    res <- adf.test(vals[,2] - beta*vals[,1], alternative = "stationary", k = 0)
    return( list(beta = beta, p.value = res$p.value) )
}
```

Apparently, adf.test has a lower bound of printed p-value at 0.01. Any value smaller p-value will create a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In adf.test(vals[, 2] - beta * vals[, 1], alternative = "stationary",  :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

Is it possible to have adf.test print out more precise p-value instead?

I know the alternative way is to suppress the warning message:

```
res <- suppressWarnings(adf.test(vals[,2] - beta*vals[,1],
                        alternative = "stationary", k = 0))
```

But printing more precise p-value would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Please inculde your data sample to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help file of `?adf.test`:

> The p-values are interpolated from Table 4.2, p. 103 of Banerjee et
>   al. (1993). If the computed statistic is outside the table of critical
>   values, then a warning message is generated.

So the short answer is no, you cannot get "more precise" p-values. At least not directly. Anyway, usually it does not make much sense to report anything other than `p<0.01`.

If you really want to get the "exact" p-value, you should probably look at the reference below. I don't have access to it, but they probably explain how they came up with their "table of critical values", so it might be possible to extend it.

> A. Banerjee, J. J. Dolado, J. W. Galbraith, and D. F. Hendry (1993):
>   Cointegration, Error Correction, and the Econometric Analysis of
>   Non-Stationary Data, Oxford University Press, Oxford.